# Do I have to manually enter info from an asp.net 4 email into an MS Database?

Tags: asp.net, database, ms-access

I have a form email, asp.net 4.0 / VB / Visual Studio, and I want it to go automatically into a Microsoft Access DB without any effort from me.  Is this possible?  I'm not a programmer, but here's the form e-mail:

> ```
> <script runat="server">
>     Protected Sub SubmitForm_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
>         If Not Page.IsValid Then Exit Sub
>
>         Dim SendResultsTo As String = "me@domain.com"
>         Dim smtpMailServer As String = "smtp.domain.com"
>         Dim smtpUsername As String = "me@domain.com"
>         Dim smtpPassword As String = "******"
>         Dim MailSubject As String = "Form Results"
>
>         Try
>             Dim txtQ As TextBox = Me.FormContent.FindControl("TextBoxQ")
>             If txtQ IsNot Nothing Then
>                 Dim ans As String = ViewState("hf1")
>                 If ans.ToLower <> txtQ.Text.ToLower Or ans.ToUpper <> txtQ.Text.ToUpper Then
>                     Me.YourForm.ActiveViewIndex = 3
>                     Exit Sub
>                 End If
>             End If
>
>             Dim FromEmail As String = SendResultsTo
>             Dim msgBody As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
>             Dim sendCC As Boolean = False
>
>
>             For Each c As Control In Me.FormContent.Controls
>                 Select Case c.GetType.ToString
>                     Case "System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox"
>                         Dim txt As TextBox = CType(c, TextBox)
>                         If txt.ID.ToLower <> "textboxq" Then
>                             msgBody.Append(txt.ID & ": " & txt.Text & vbCrLf & vbCrLf)
>                         End If
>                         If txt.ID.ToLower = "email" Then
>                             FromEmail = txt.Text
>                         End If
>                         If txt.ID.ToLower = "subject" Then
>                             MailSubject = txt.Text
>                         End If
>                     Case "System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox"
>                         Dim chk As CheckBox = CType(c, CheckBox)
>                         If chk.ID.ToLower = "checkboxcc" Then
>                             If chk.Checked Then sendCC = True
>                         Else
>                             msgBody.Append(chk.ID & ": " & chk.Checked & vbCrLf & vbCrLf)
>                         End If
>
>                     Case "System.Web.UI.WebControls.RadioButton"
>                         Dim rad As RadioButton = CType(c, RadioButton)
>                         msgBody.Append(rad.ID & ": " & rad.Checked & vbCrLf & vbCrLf)
>                     Case "System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList"
>                         Dim ddl As DropDownList = CType(c, DropDownList)
>                         msgBody.Append(ddl.ID & ": " & ddl.SelectedValue & vbCrLf & vbCrLf)
>                 End Select
>             Next
>             msgBody.AppendLine()
>
>             msgBody.Append("Browser: " & Request.UserAgent & vbCrLf & vbCrLf)
>             msgBody.Append("IP Address: " & Request.UserHostAddress & vbCrLf & vbCrLf)
>             msgBody.Append("Server Date & Time: " & DateTime.Now & vbCrLf & vbCrLf)
>
>             Dim myMessage As System.Net.Mail.MailMessage = New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage()
>             myMessage.To.Add(SendResultsTo)
>             myMessage.From = New System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(FromEmail)
>             myMessage.Subject = MailSubject
>             myMessage.Body = msgBody.ToString
>             myMessage.IsBodyHtml = False
>             If sendCC Then myMessage.CC.Add(FromEmail)
>
>
>             Dim basicAuthenticationInfo As New System.Net.NetworkCredential(smtpUsername, smtpPassword)
>             Dim MailObj As New System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient(smtpMailServer)
>             MailObj.Credentials = basicAuthenticationInfo
>             MailObj.Send(myMessage)
>
>             Me.YourForm.ActiveViewIndex = 1
>         Catch
>             Me.YourForm.ActiveViewIndex = 2
>         End Try
>     End Sub
>
>     Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
>         If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
>             Dim lbl As Label = Me.FormContent.FindControl("labelq")
>             If lbl IsNot Nothing Then
>                 Dim rq(3) As String
>                 rq(0) = "Is fire hot or cold?"
>                 rq(1) = "Is ice hot or cold?"
>                 rq(2) = "Is water wet or dry?"
>
>                 Dim ra(3) As String
>                 ra(0) = "hot"
>                 ra(1) = "cold"
>                 ra(2) = "wet"
>
>                 Dim rnd As New Random
>                 Dim rn As Integer = rnd.Next(0, 3)
>                 lbl.Text = rq(rn)
>                 ViewState("hf1") = ra(rn)
>             End If
>         End If
>     End Sub
> </script> </asp:Content> <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server"> <h1>CONTACT HEALTH
> ```
>
> NUTTS AND WORK FROM THE COMFORT OF YOUR OWN HOME!
>           
>               
>                           
>                       Enter your Email Address:
>                       
>                       
>                   
>                   * Required
>                   * Please enter a valid email address.
>                   
>                   
>                           
>                       Subject:
>                       
>                       
>                   
>                   * Required
>                   
>                   
>                           
>                       Please type your message below:
>                       * Required
>                       
>                       
>                       
>                   
>                   
>                   
>                           
>                       First Name:
>                       
>                   
>                   * Required
>                   
>                   
>                           
>                       Last Name:
>                       
>                       
>                   
>                   * Required
>                   
>                   
>                           
>                       Phone Number:
>                       
>                       
>                   
>                   * Required
>                   * Please enter a valid U.S. phone number (including dashes).
>                   
>                   
>                           
>                       City:
>                       
>                       
>                   
>                   * Required
>                   
>                   
>                           
>                       State/Province:
>                       
>                       
>                   
>                   * Required
>                   
>                   
>                           
>                   
>                   
>                   
>                   
>                   
>                   
>                   
>               
>               
>                   Your message has been sent. Thank you for contacting us.
>               
>               
>                   Due to technical difficulty, your message may NOT have been sent.
>               
>               
>                   You did not correctly answer the anti-spam question. Please go back and try again.

When someone fills out the form, I get an e-mail like this:

> Email: rmajeski@yahoo.com
>
> Subject: I need A Job
>
> Message: Me wants job today okay? Thank you for J.O.B
>
> First_Name: Rich
>
> Last_Name: Majeski
>
> Phone: xxx-xxx-xxxx
>
> City: Hockeytown
>
> State: Michigan
>
> Browser: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101
>   Firefox/12.0
>
> IP Address: 108.224.49.14
>
> Server Date & Time: 5/15/2012 6:03:33 AM

How can I make this go into a Microsoft Access DB automatically, without me having to do it manually?  Any guidance would be truly appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: You'll have to modify your page code to make it happen, there's no auto-magic way. You'll have to hire a programmer.

Comment: I haven't tried anything because I don't know how to do things.  But I'm not programming-illiterate ... I mean, if someone showed me a tutorial or told me how to do things in Layman's terms, I could figure it out.  But being a startup company, I don't have the money to hire a programmer, which is why I'm taking on the responsibility.  Regardless, thank you Loktar, and Filburt, for taking the time to look at my issue and offer a solution.

Comment: I mean, I made ussvision.com and healthynutts.com solely off of nice people from Stack helping me out ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a read on tutorials on Office add-in programming.
One way to go would be having this add-in looking at every incoming email in Outlook and parse the fields into corresponding variables. After that you can create a database connection to a MS Access database file to insert the data with an SQL-Insert DML statement.
I think this would be the easiest way for you, as programming this will not take too many lines of code. But MS Outlook has to be running!

The best way would of course be to create the database connection asynchronously (using ODBC) in ASP.NET. There should be a lot tutorials on that online.